# Substitute a new man page for an older one

Tags: symlink, man, shared-library

I've just built (from source) a current version (ver 2.1) of `libgpiod` on my RPi 4B. There are six (6) "command-line tools" included in the source tarball for `libgpiod`. During the `make install` process, these tools - and their new `man` pages - were installed in sub-folders under `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

- man pages: `./share/man/man1`
- binary exe tools: `./bin`

I did not un-install the existing `libgpiod` package from my system. For now (until I figure out whether or not to keep ver 2.1, or an up-to-date package is released), I'm creating symlinks in `/usr/bin` pointing to the new tools in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin`. But I'm unclear on how to handle the `man`uals. I want to see the new `man` pages; e.g. when I enter `man gpioset`, I want to see the man page in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/man/man1/gpioset.1`.

As RPi OS is a Debian derivative, I'd *expect* that manuals were installed IAW *Debian convention* (whatever that might be). I did run a `whereis` against the name of one of the *6 command line tools*, and got the following:

```bash
$ whereis gpioinfo
gpioinfo: /usr/bin/gpioinfo /usr/bin/gpioinfo.old /usr/share/man/man1/gpioinfo.1.gz
```

And I find all 6 manuals in `/usr/share/man/man1` (as *"gzip"*-compressed files). I suppose *one way* to make the substitution of *"new-for-old*" man pages would be to move (`mv`) the old manuals, and put links to the new ones in their place. But I was hoping for something *more elegant* than that - perhaps a "one-liner" somewhere that pointed to the location of the new manuals in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/man/man1`. Is there such a *one-liner*?

Is there a way to set this up on an *ad-hoc* basis - until the new `libgpiod` package is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different options, depending on the precise version of `man` that you have installed. So far I have identified configuration files named `/etc/man.conf`, `/etc/man_db.conf`, `/etc/manpath.config`. Fortunately, the one you need should be referenced from `man man`, and may be further described by name (for example, `man man.conf`). However, you shouldn't need to edit those yourself and here are two suggestions, depending on whether you need the man pages to be accessible by multiple users or really just yourself:

1. Put your man pages in the correctly named directory under a known system location. For local installations this would typically be `/usr/local/share/man`. So you would move or copy the files from your local `./share/man/man1` to the directory `/usr/local/share/man/man1`.
2. Set the environment variable `MANPATH` to a colon-separated list of directory trees to search for manual pages. The slightly complicating factor here is to know the original search path, and on some systems you can run `manpath` (or maybe `manpath -g`) to obtain this value.

   Here are a couple of suggestions that should work, with the first being preferred:

   ```
   MANPATH="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/man:$(manpath)"
   MANPATH="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man"
   ```

Comment: *"There is a manpath configuration entry that will allow you to specify your new man pages directory before the system ones"*.      I'm sorry, but after reading `man 5 manpath`, `man manpath`  and `/etc/manpath.config`, I'm just not seeing how to **selectively** alter the manpath for the 6 tools I asked about.

Comment: @Seamus there you go, examples added

Comment: `MANPATH` is created by you, so until you set it, it won't exist